# MYSQL - Select all rows that don't join with other table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables, first stores the announcements and second stores the list of users that have read the announcements. I'm trying to capture all announcements with status of read or unread. If the second table doesnot contain a row of user_id corresponding with that announcement_id, it's unread. Here's how it looks like

Announcements

```
id | content | announce_on
1  | foo     | 2016-11-10
2  | bar     | 2016-11-11
3  | zim     | 2016-11-12
```

Announcement View Count

```
id  | user_id | announcement_id
1   | 1       | 1
2   | 1       | 2
3   | 2       | 1
4   | 2       | 3
```

(user 1 has read announcement 1 and 2, user 2 has read announcement 1)

The best thing I've got so far is

```
SELECT
  *,
  a.id AS annId
FROM
  announcement a
LEFT JOIN
  announcement_view_count avc
ON
  avc.announcement_id = a.id
WHERE
  a.announce_on <= CURRENT_DATE AND (avc.user_id = 1 OR avc.user_id IS NULL)
```

The problem is that I will not get announcement 3 at all. The `avc.user_id IS NULL` part is not working right. Announcement 3 is not showing up because it has been viewed by user 2.

It's hard to explain but I want to load all anouncements and have one column that could tell me if the announcement has been viewed by a particular user. (who's id is available). Can someone give me a hint?

I've also tried NOT EXISTS and NOT IN but they return empty results.

Comment: no one can try your query because the tables you have posted do not match the query

Comment: Your "Best thing so far" is making references to column names that you have not provided in your description. Based upon the table data you provided, what does dates have to do with it. Do you need to tell us more,or is what you have already provided, what you intended? I Only see two tables with 3 columns each.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did't wanted to include uneccessary columns. Please check again

Comment: because announcement 3 has been read? `4   | 2       | 3`

Comment: show us what are the expected results

Comment: Something like `SELECT announcement_id, count(*) as count FROM table WHERE count < user_count;`. Just as an idea?

Comment: What should the desired result look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you need. Lets see: you need the list of all announcements with an additional column saying if the announcement have been read by an specific user. In that case you need to add the filter for the user id inside the join condition and not as a global condition in the where clause. You can use something like this:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    (avc.announcement_id is not NULL) wasRead
FROM
    announcement a
LEFT JOIN
    announcement_view_count avc
ON
    (avc.announcement_id = a.id AND avc.user_id = 1)
WHERE
    a.announce_on <= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Brilliant man. I was trying to capture the same thing from IS NULL part. If you remove all 'filters' the user_id comes up as null which is what's captured by your code. Who downvoted?

Comment: No idea who downvoted, I would love to know what is wrong with my approach so I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but maybe you can use this to create an extra column where you can store if the user has read the announcement.

```
CASE case_value
  WHEN when_value THEN statements
  ELSE statements
END
```